# How to add Excel sheet to console application

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Can any one explain the process of adding excel file in C# and What are the requirements for that?
Is it necessary to install MS Excel in the system for using of Excel in C#

Comment: What do you mean by *adding excel file in C#*? Do you mean you want to access some data from an excel sheet?

Comment: yes,but with out using the MSExcel,it is not installed in my pc,so i want to crate a excel file using the c sharp and access that...

Comment: i think you'll need to back up a bit and explain exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: DownRated: Most of the required information is left on readers imagination. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: "process of adding excel file in c sharp" add an excel file in a csharp project as a resource?

Comment: If you just want to create a file that Excel can read, just use CSV (Comma Separated Values) format -- it's easy to create and will by default open with Excel on a computer that has Excel installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can read data from Excel spreadsheet *without* having Excel installed, using ADO.Net. Here is a [sample](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/196) for how to do this.

However, your question is a little vague. Since you do not have Excel installed, which of these do you really want to do:

1. Read an XLS file that has been created by Excel earlier.
2. Write an XLS file that will be read by Excel later.
3. Use the computational or solving facilities that Excel provides without actually using Excel.

You may get more useful answers if you clarify.

Comment: Any particular reason not to use ADO.NET? It is always available (if the .Net framework is installed).

Comment: You cannot use Excel interop unless you have Excel installed on your system. ADO.NET seems to be the only way to go unless you want to develop a module to read the Excel file's format. There may be some third-party controls available to read Excel data.

Comment: The _sample_ link is outdated

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will let you use Excel files in any .NET application (Console app, WinForms, ASP.NET, etc...) without having Excel installed.

You can see live samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

From past experience I would suggest you use a dedicated component like [Gembox](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/) or [Aspose Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) for this purpose. Besides it being more straightforward, you don't need to have Excel installed and you won't have deployment and licensing issues.